# Determine type of template parameter in Visual Studio 2008 without overloading

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates

I know this question was asked before, but I am trying to specifically find out if it could be resolved **in Visual Studio 2008 SP1 (C++ version 9), without function overloading, and without boost or other 3rd party library**.

```
template<typename T>T foo()
{
    #if (T is char*) // return something
    #elif (T is int) // return something different
    . . .
    #endif
}
```

T could be simple builtin type (not a class). Input parameter of type T not required.

For some reason, compiler tells "'is_same' : is not a member of 'std::tr1'". Probably, is_same was introduced after Visual Studio 2008 SP1, although theoretically it should be available.

I am wondering if it is another "impossible" undertaking.
Thanks!

Comment: Why not just implement [`std::is_same`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same)?

Comment: You can provide template specializations for each special case you want to handle, similar to overloading.

Comment: I tried - compiler not taking it (I wrote about it). This is clean Visual Studio 2008 wit SP1 installed. I would guess it should be available, but it isn't.

Comment: @Yksisarinen - tried to implement a single function body. If absolutely impossible to do otherwise, will have to do that.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible to get it to work without `if constexpr` (C++17) or multiple specializations. Preprocessor directives like `#if` won't help. And without `if constexpr` you must make every branch valid for every template parameter, so you can only return types that are convertible between each other. Otherwise one branch would be invalid, like trying to `return char*` in `foo<int>`

Comment: Hmm, the answer was deleted, but it worked fine.

Comment: Unfortunately, didn't notice who posted the answer - it was deleted before I finished checking if it works. It does beautifully. Thanks!

Comment: i deleted it because I made a stupid mistake. It doesn't "work". You cannot return an `int` in a function that is declared to return eg a `std::string`. A solution depends on more details. What do you want to return? What types exactly can `T` be?

Comment: @AndreiKalantarian I believe the suggestion from cigien was not to *use* `std::is_same` but to *implement* it. That is, define (not in `std`) a class template that serves the same role as `std::is_same`. The linked article gives one possible implementation you could use.

Comment: @idclev That's no problem, I wasn't expecting exact answer to paste in my code, that's why it took some time to see if it works. T could be any numeric type; and I added bool as specialization. It can't be pretty much anything else, but that wasn't needed. My problem was is_same, and your solution works nicely. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That's what I was looking for:

```
template <typename T,typename U>
struct is_same
{
    static const bool value = false;
};
template <typename T>
struct is_same<T,T> {
    static const bool value = true;
};

class INI
{
public:
    . . .
    template<typename T> T    getValue(LPCTSTR path, T    deflt);
    template<bool>       bool getValue(LPCTSTR path, bool deflt);
private:
    LPCTSTR data;
};

template<typename T> T INI::getValue(LPCTSTR path, T deflt)
{
    if (is_same<T, _int64>::value)          return (T)_strtoi64(data, NULL, 10);
    if (is_same<T, unsigned _int64>::value) return (T)_strtoui64(data, NULL, 10);
    if (is_same<T, int>::value            ||
        is_same<T, short>::value          ||
        is_same<T, char>::value)            return (T)strtol(data, NULL, 10);
    if (is_same<T, unsigned int>::value   || 
        is_same<T, unsigned short>::value || 
        is_same<T, unsigned char>::value)   return (T)strtoul(data, NULL, 10);
    if (is_same<T, double>::value         ||
        is_same<T, float>::value)           return (T)atof(data);
    return deflt;
}
template<> bool INI::getValue(LPCTSTR path, bool deflt)
{
    return (data[0] == '1') ? true : (data[0] == "0") ? false : deflt;
}
```

In newer C++ compiler I removed is_same declarations and inserted std:: before each is_same, all works same way.

And, looks like, function parameter of class T is required - at least, for the old C++ compiler.

Thanks!

Comment: Your example code does not match the question's. The question asked about a function template, and your answer gives a class template (with member functions, but that's not the same thing as a function template). *Since it's your question, I do not doubt that this code addresses your particular situation. However, it may look bad to future readers who have similar questions.*

Comment: the crucial part that doesnt match the question is that in your solution the function takes a parameter, not in the quesiton. If the function takes a `T` as parmater you should simply use overloads.

Comment: I came back to C++ after many years of C# and javascript coding,and apologize for not exact terminology (although I tried). And, no, I wasn't looking for class template. The template method goes into the big legacy class. The code sample in original question matches the final production code sans function parameters (and I removed some unrelated stuff). Critical part was checking the variable type inside the template function. Never imagined it to be *that* portable. Thanks again to @idclev for posting the solution!

Comment: @AndreiKalantarian note that I removed the part I considered problematic from my answer. What you do with it is your buisness ;). Seriously, I would never let your `INI::getvalue` pass a code review because I dont see why it cant be done with overloads and your method template pretends to be fine with all `T` but it isnt. Anyhow, perhaps there are constraints that I am not aware of and im glad to help

Comment: The reason of not adding that as overloads was attempt to keep the class definition simple: in fact, each overload should be doubled to handle either LPCWSTR and LPCSTR. Having a big amount of new definitions would be less appropriate for the project - although functionally it is cleaner. Originally I was looking to do without parameter of type T (default is usually 0), but looks like it is impossible or overall complicated.

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.

Comment: @Barrnet Chou For some reason community did not appreciate neither the question, nor the answer. I thank idclev 463035818 for providing the vital clue. The solution went into production code.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know that version of MSVC, but suppose you don't have `std::is_same`, then it is rather simple to write it yourself:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T,typename U>
struct is_same {
    static const bool value = false;
};
template <typename T>
struct is_same<T,T> {
    static const bool value = true;
};

int main() {
    std::cout << is_same<int,int>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << is_same<int,double>::value << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
1
0
```

Comment: str::is_same added at C++ version 11. Theoretically version 9 I am working with, should have std::tr1::is_same, but it doesn't compile. I mentioned it in the question.

Comment: @AndreiKalantarian I have read the question, but as you don't show the code nor the compiler error I cannot know what is the problem with your code. My answer should be fine in any version of the compiler (afaik)

Comment: @AndreiKalantarian I am not using `std::is_same` in the code, if that is what you mean...